# Is there an easy way to test your code against standard's named requirements?

Tags: c++, std, standards

Let's say I wanted to write an iterator for my custom container which uses a custom allocator but still adheres to the C++ standard so that I can be sure it will work with standard algorithms. Is there an easy way to check if all of the above meet the requirements of, say *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*, *Container* and *Allocator*?

I am aware that those requirements are listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator), but let's just say the wording leaves a bit of room for ambiguity at times (*LegacyContiguousIterator* is literally *LegacyRandomAccessIterator* hoping that the virtual memory will map 1-to-1 to its underlying physical storage as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: When it comes to C++, the answer to every question that begins with "is there an easy way to..." is nearly always going to be "no". That rule still holds true here.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#C.2B.2B20_iterator_concepts

Comment: @AlanBirtles That might be what I am looking for, thanks. Do you also happen to know some "noob friendly" tutorials on the subject of concepts?

Comment: @BigTemp: "*LegacyContiguousIterator is literally LegacyRandomAccessIterator hoping that the virtual memory will map 1-to-1 to its underlying physical storage as far as I'm concerned*" That's not what it's saying. It's saying that, for any given element referenced by an iterator, the element referenced by the next iterator if any must be the same object as incrementing a pointer to the previous element by the size of the value_type. It has nothing to do with virtual memory; the iterator must be isomorphic with a pointer into an array of `value_type`.

Answer (score 3):

With C++20 you can `static_assert(...)` that concepts are met:

```
class some_iterator { ... };
static_assert(requires std::random_access_iterator<some_iterator>);
```

Comment: `std::random_access_iterator` is not the same requirement as LegacyRandomAccessIterator

Comment: @NicolBolas: sure. The standard library doesn’t provide a concept for exactly that. It does provide `std::contiguous_iterator`. However, my point is that with C++20 it is fairly straight forward to test against concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If C++ had an easy way to test whether a type fit a concept... C++20 wouldn't have needed to *create* that mechanism. This is after all what C++20 concepts are.

Of course, the C++20 feature introduces standard library concepts which are similar to but not equivalent to the "Legacy" versions. That is, `Cpp17RandomAccessIterator` is not the same thing as `std::random_access_iterator`. They're pretty close, but the C++20 testable concept is able to permit things which the C++17 named requirement cannot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unified validation method for `STL` implementations. Every implementation provides own tests. You can look at examples of [Microsoft STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/tree/master/tests/std/tests). Adapting tests for your own implementations should not be hard as an interface is the same.